# The use of cut in shell / bash scripting

Tags: shell

can anyone explain me use use of following syntax

```
  var5=$@   #All the arguments are individually double quoted
var1=`echo ${var5} | cut -d "=" -f2| cut -d "|" -f1`
```

I just started learning shell scripting, please explain me exactly what this part does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line should be easy to understand. It simply stores all arguments passed to the command in a variable.

If you start your script as

```
bash script.sh these are my parameters
```

Then var5 will contain "these are my parameters 1=".

Then the second line, it is also a variable assignment which consists out of 3 commands:

```
echo ${var5}
```

This will simply echo var5 being the input to the program.

```
cut -d "=" -f2
```

This will take the input, split the string by the '=' delimiter and take the second field. If var5 contains a=b=c then this command will return 'b'.

```
cut -d "|" -f1
```

This is similar as the previous command, but will split using '|' as a delimiter and will take the first field.

Given that you invoke the command as 
`bash k.sh paramater="a|b invalid=param"`

Then:

- "parameter=a|b invalid=param" will be assigned to var5
- "parameter=a|b invalid=param" will be echo'ed
- "a|b invalid" will be the result of the first cut.
- "a" will be the result of the second cut and this will be stored in var1.